# How to get APIKey for Nuke.Build Nuget push step to internal Azure DevOps feed?

Tags: azure-devops, api-key, nuke-build, nuget-push

I am trying to do the `Nuke.Build` push to Azure DevOps internal feed.
If I do it within Azure Pipelines, and add a step to publish the nuget, it will give me a step like this:

For the classic:

```
steps:
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'dotnet push'
  inputs:
    command: push
    publishVstsFeed: 'faeeeeee-eeee-eeee-eeee-c48a92cb3804/2a06fd96-0000-0000-0000-643ff5710000'
```

for the yaml:

```
  - task: NuGetCommand@2
    inputs:
      command: 'push'
      packagesToPush: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/**/*.nupkg;!$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/**/*.symbols.nupkg'
      nuGetFeedType: 'internal'
      publishVstsFeed: 'faeeeeee-eeee-eeee-eeee-c48a92cb3804/2a06fd96-0000-0000-0000-643ff5710000'
```

In both cases it relies on the internal variable or token that is used to publish to the internal NuGet Feed.

Now, when I do it from Nuke, I have the Publish step like this:

```
Target Publish => _ => _
    .DependsOn(Pack)
    .Executes(() =>
    {
        DotNetTasks.DotNetNuGetPush(x => x
        .SetApiKey("????")
        .SetSource("https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/company/project/_packaging/feed/nuget/v3/index.json")
        .SetTargetPath(PackagesDirectory));
    });
```

I get from that:

> error: Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized).

So the API Key is needed.

Where do I get the ApiKey from? There got to be a way of importing the secret from the pipeline, so I could use it from the Publish step in Nuke.Build (besides the PAT way) in a non-interactive way?

Comment: So far I have not figured out how to do that. For now I am using secret variables in the pipeline, in yaml I use `variables` to import the secrets and then use `parameter.json` file in Nuke to import these variables. After that, I use `DotNetTasks.DotNetNuGetAddSource` with PAT to add the source to the nuget settings, and then I am able to Push the *.nupkg file to the feed. I wish it were possible to do that with the internal identity/account since everything is within Azure DevOps, but no luck with that.

Answer (score 0):

hopefully I'm not to late for your problem.

Here is how we are publishing nuget packages in our Azure Pipeline.

Given you are using parameters for NuGetSource and NuGetApiKey.

```
    Target NugetPublish => definition => definition
        .Requires(() => NuGetApiKey, () => NuGetSource)
        .Executes(() =>
        {
            DotNetNuGetPush(pushSettings => pushSettings
                .SetSource(NuGetSource)
                .SetApiKey(NuGetApiKey)
                .EnableNoSymbols()
                .EnableSkipDuplicate()
                .CombineWith(PushPackageFiles, (settings, path) => settings
                    .SetTargetPath(path)));
        });
```

In our Azure Pipeline I am using nuke like this

```
      # this authenticates the pipeline with the azure artifacts storage
      - task: NuGetAuthenticate@1

      # feedName is the name of the feed within your nuget.config, ApiKey is static AzureDevops to tell the preauthentication should be used
      - pwsh: './build.ps1 NugetPublish --NuGetSource feedName --NuGetApiKey AzureDevops'
```

In your nuget.config you define the feed:

```
<add key="feedName" value="https://org.pkgs.visualstudio.com/software/_packaging/feedName/nuget/v3/index.json" />
```

Best regards